# DocumentDb select is working on QueryExplorer but not returning correct results in my code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

For the following JSON object I store in my DocumentDb database, I created a SELECT query and tested it on Azure Portal using the Query Explorer. The results I'm getting on the portal are correct.

I then use the same exact query in my code -- using DocumentDb client and the result are not exactly right.

Here's the full JSON document stored in DocumentDb

```
{
   id: 987456,
   name: "Jerry Buss Family Trust",
   sportsTeams: [
      {
         id: 123,
         type: "Professional Basketball Team",
         team: "Los Angeles Lakers",
         coach: "Byron Scott",
         players: [
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Brandon Bass",
                position: "Forward"
            },
            {
                id: 24,
                name: "Kobe Bryant",
                position: "Forward-Guard"
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: "Ryan Kelly",
                position: "Forward"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         id: 345,
         type: "Professional Hockey Team"
         team: "Los Angeles Kings",
         coach: "Darryl Sutter",
         players: [
            {
                id: 15,
                name: "Andy Andreoff",
                position: "Forward"
            },
            {
                id: 27,
                name: "Alec Martinez",
                position: "Defenseman"
            },
            {
                id: 32,
                name: "Jonathan Quick",
                position: "Goalie"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to get only the sports teams under "Jerry Buss Family Trust" document. Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT c.id as teamId, c.name as teamName, c.players
FROM a JOIN c in a.sportsTeams
WHERE a.id = "987456"
```

When I run this on Azure Portal Query Explorer, I get exactly what I want which is id and name from the main document and an array of all players.

However, when I use this query in my code, I get the main record and correct number of items in the players array but each array item has NULL values. So I get something like this:

```
{
   id: 123,
   name: "Los Angeles Lakers"
   players: [
       {
           id: 0
           name: NULL,
           position: NULL
       },
       // etc. IMPORTANT: I do get the CORRECT number of sub-documents that correspond to players.
       // Also note that the shape of the sub document is correct.
       // The issue is that the data is missing!
   ]
}
```

The code that performs the READ query is this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ReadQuery<T>(string collectionId, SqlQuerySpec sql)
{
    var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_dbName, collectionId);

    var result = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(collectionLink, query, null).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

After this code runs, I'm inspecting the result and like I said, I do get the main document data correctly. I also get the correct number/shape of sub documents but the sub docs don't have any data in them.

Any idea what's causing this issue?

Comment: Can you show the code that defines type T? I typically always use type <dynamic> to avoid typing problems when I change schema. You might want to try that.

Comment: Agree with @LarryMaccherone, sounds to me like a desrialization error to me. you're getting the correct resultset, but it looks like the objects in your code are not being populated correctly. Is this correct? Can you verify by checking the wire response using something like Fiddler.